# jQuery - Adding text to already dynamic text

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button as follows

```
<input type="radio" name="thisone" value="yes">
```

I then have a bit of text like so

```
<span class="iamtext">hey ya'll, im some text</span>
```

Now this text is being dynamically written in from the database, so assuming i dont know what the text is, how would i then add 'and im epic' to the end of that text only if someone clicks the radio button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(':radio[name="yes"]').click(function() {
    $('.iamtext').text(function(index, oldText) {
        return oldText + ' and im epic';
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/abXBU/).

#### Update

> Just one little thing, if there was a 'no' radio button next to that, is it possible to be able to delete that ' and im epic' text and revert back to the dynamic text that was there before without the addition?

Try this code...

```
$(':radio[name="yes"]').click(function() {
    $('.iamtext').append('<span> and im epic</span>');
});

$(':radio[name="no"]').click(function() {
    $('.iamtext').find('span').remove();
});
```

Comment: @alex - Just one little thing, if there was a 'no' radio button next to that, is it possible to be able to delete that ' and im epic' text and revert back to the dynamic text that was there before without the addition?

Comment: @BigJobbies In that case, I would wrap the added text in a `span` and toggle its visibility based on the checkboxes' state.

Comment: That is interesting ... ummm sorry to be a pain, but could you possibly give me an example of how this goes? ... im such a jquery newbie

Comment: @alex - Niceeee thanks for that ... can the .find thingo be used to find a class name aswell?

Comment: @BigJobbies It sure can, you can pass any jQuery selector to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one:**

**JQUERY:**

```
$("input:radio").click(function(){
    var vTextTobeadded = "and im epic";
    $("span.iamtext").append(vTextTobeadded);
});
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oxuyu4)**